# Kubernetes memory leak troubleshooting

Tags: kubernetes, memory-leaks, systemd, cgroups

I upgraded our cluster to 1.20.14 and noticed the memory leaks. We have 5 cronjobs running every minute and I placed them on the same node without any other workload running (other than system pods, e.g. flannel, kube-proxy and node exporter, etc.

I found the memory usage is increasing over time. [image]
The node will become unresponsive when all memory is used. Had to reboot it to release the memory. If I cordon the node, the memory will stay the same level. I think all of our nodes has this issue, but it is amplified when running the cronjob as the pods are creating and deleted frequently with cronjobs.

I also noticed that the pods are not cleaned up under `/sys/fs/cgroup/kubepods/besteffort/`. I have 8 pods running but 7k directories there. Those pods are also listed with `systemd-cgls -a`. I'm wonder if it is related.
[image]

Here is the screenshot for `systemd-cgtop`:
[image]

Any suggestion on how do I troubleshoot this? Thanks!

System info:

- Kuberenetes: 1.20.14
- OS: Flatcar Stable 3033.2.3
- cgroup: v2
- container runtime: containerd
- cgroupfs: Systemd
- containerd: 1.5.9

Comment: Additional info: I provisioned another node with 1.19.16. There is no memory leak on that node. I also noticed that on 1.19.16 node, under /sys/fs/cgroup, there is not kubepods directory, only kubepods.slice, where on 1.20.14 node, both exist. And all those empty pods in the screenshots are under kubepods directory. I wonder if those pods are placed in wrong directory and didn't get cleaned up.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is fixed in by the following PRs: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/100326, https://github.com/kubernetes/utils/pull/228 and https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/106473

Update to 1.21.11 fixed the issue. The fixes are not back ported to 1.20